# TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable when accessing dtypes of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, typeerror

As it is [Duplicate], I have raised this to be removed. Kindly do not rollback.

Comment: It is bad to post code or data as pictures.  There is no way to copy and paste a picture into a code editor. So it will be much harder, and thus less likely, for someone to help. To get the most out of the site it is important to [ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), that includes creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no ambiguity here. `file` is a dataframe, and `dtypes` is an attribute.

```
df
        productView  order
userId                    
A               4.5    5.0
B               1.5    2.5
C               4.0    2.0
D               2.0    3.0

df.dtypes
productView    float64
order          float64
dtype: object
```

When you access `dtypes`, a Series is returned:

```
type(df.dtypes)
pandas.core.series.Series
```

When you call `df.dtypes()`, you are effectively doing `series = df.dtype; series()` which is invalid, since `series` is an object (not a function, or an object with `__call__` defined).

In the second case, `dtype` isn't even a valid attribute/method of `df`, and so an `AttributeError` is raised.

TLDR; The first error is raised on the `dtype` series, the second is raised on the original dataframe `df`.